# Get list of Page Albums using Facebook PHP SDK v5

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I want to use *Facebook PHP SDK v5* to get a list of photo albums for a Page.

I am following the instructions at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.4/page/albums, which are as follows:

```
/* PHP SDK v5.0.0 */
/* make the API call */
$request = new FacebookRequest(
  $session,
  'GET',
  '/{page-id}/albums'
);
$response = $request->execute();
$graphObject = $response->getGraphObject();
/* handle the result */
```

This does however seem to be incorrect as there is no "`execute`" function in the FacebookRequest class.

In addition, there also needs to be the `access_token` passed as the second variable to the `FacebookRequest` construct.

My full code is as follows:

```
require_once("classes/Facebook/autoload.php");
use Facebook\Facebook;
use Facebook\FacebookApp;
use Facebook\FacebookRequest;
$config = array();
$config['app_id'] = '{app_id}';
$config['app_secret'] = '{secret}';
$config['default_graph_version'] = 'v2.4';
$fb = new Facebook($config);
$app= new FacebookApp($config['app_id'],$config['app_secret']);

$request=new FacebookRequest($app,"{access_token}",'GET','/{page_id}/albums');
$response = $request->execute();
$graphObject = $response->getGraphObject();
print_r($graphObject);
```

This just produces the

> fatal error: Call to undefined method
>   Facebook\FacebookRequest::execute()

Can someone point me in the direction of the correct code?

Comment: https://graph.facebook.com/audi/albums?access_token=xxxxxxxx gives you a list of albums

Comment: Thanks @Criesto - that seems to work sufficiently for my purposes. Would still like an answer to the question though. Would be cleaner to do it through the SDK.

Comment: Why the downvote on this?

Comment: I didn't downvote you. LOL

Comment: Sorry, wasn't directing that at you Criesto!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Have a look at the docs at

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/FacebookRequest/5.0.0#overview
- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/gettingstarted/5.0.0#making-requests

Sample code:

```
$fbApp = new Facebook\FacebookApp('{app-id}', '{app-secret}');
$request = new Facebook\FacebookRequest($fbApp, '{access-token}', 'GET', '/{page_id}/albums');

// OR

$fb = new Facebook\Facebook(/* . . . */);
$request = $fb->request('GET', '/{page_id}/albums');

// Send the request to Graph
try {
  $response = $fb->getClient()->sendRequest($request);
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
  // When Graph returns an error
  echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
  exit;
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
  // When validation fails or other local issues
  echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
  exit;
}

$graphNode = $response->getGraphNode();

print_r($graphNode);
```

Comment: you saved my day :) great.. awesome.. :)

Comment: @AbhishekGoel can you please share your code, how can i access pictures,, i am not getting images.

Comment: @HamzaZafeer Don't remember where is that code and where i used it :P