# Fatal error: Call to undefined method Facebook\FacebookRequest::execute()

Tags: php, facebook, sdk

My code returns this error:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined method Facebook\FacebookRequest::execute()
```

How can I fix this error?

If I use this request I get the response that I want. Is there a way to map the response that I received?

```
$response = $fb->get('/me/photos?fields=created_time,from,height,icon,id,link,tags,name,picture&limit=2', $_SESSION['facebook_access_token']);
```

My code:

```
$request = new Facebook\FacebookRequest( null,
          $_SESSION['fb_access_token'],
          'GET',
          '/me/photos',
          array(
            'fields' => 'picture',
            'limit' => '2'
          )
        );

$response = $request->execute();
$graphObject = $response->getGraphObject();
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get list of Page Albums using Facebook PHP SDK v5](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32395951/get-list-of-page-albums-using-facebook-php-sdk-v5)

Comment: Thank you @Hackerman but is there a way on how to map the response from FacebookReponse?