# Call to undefined method Facebook\FacebookRequest::execute()

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Here is my code for posting a post in a facebook group using facebook graph API.but it return an error.

**METHOD 1**

```
include 'vendor/autoload.php';
use Facebook\FacebookApp;
use Facebook\Facebook;
use Facebook\FacebookRequest;

$app_id         = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
$psswd          = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';

$group_id       = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';

$app = new FacebookApp($app_id, $psswd);
$request = new FacebookRequest(
  $app,
  'POST',
  '/'.$group_id.'/feed',
  array (
    'message' => 'This is a test message',
  )
);
$response = $request->execute();
$graphObject = $response->getGraphObject();
```

ERROR

> Fatal error: Call to undefined method
>   Facebook\FacebookRequest::execute()

**METHOD 2**

```
session_start();
error_reporting(-1);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
include 'vendor/autoload.php';
use Facebook\FacebookApp;
use Facebook\Facebook;
use Facebook\FacebookRequest;

$app_id         = 'xxxxxxxxxxxx';
$psswd          = 'xxxxxxxxxxxx';

$group_id       = 'xxxxxxxxxxxx';
$fb = new Facebook([
  'app_id'     => $app_id,
  'app_secret' => $psswd,
  'default_graph_version' => 'v2.4',
  ]);
$request = $fb->request('POST', '/'.$group_id.'/feed',array('message'=>'This is a test message'));

// Send the request to Graph
try {
  $response = $fb->getClient()->sendRequest($request);
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
  // When Graph returns an error
  echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
  exit;
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
  // When validation fails or other local issues
  echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
  exit;
}

$graphNode = $response->getGraphNode();

print_r($graphNode);
```

**ERROR**

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception
>   'Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException' with message 'You must
>   provide an access token.'

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get list of Page Albums using Facebook PHP SDK v5](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32395951/get-list-of-page-albums-using-facebook-php-sdk-v5)

Comment: answer in error msg 'You must provide an access token.'

Comment: @BharatDangar how to provide that access token and how to get?

Comment: Have you created a Facebook application, @ShijinTR?

Comment: see this https://www.google.co.in/#q=post+in+a+facebook+group+using+facebook+graph+API+using+php

Comment: @GiamPy Yes, from settings i obtained App ID  and app secret

Answer (score 0):

Here is my code for posting into facebook group and it's working

```
<?php
// load autoload for composer packages
require('vendor/autoload.php');

// load the named consts file that contains all the sensitive info
require('includes/variables.php');

// load phpmailer settings
require('phpmailer.php');

$appsecret_proof = hash_hmac('sha256', token, app_secret);

// fb api
$fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
    'app_id' => app_id,
    'app_secret' => app_secret,
    'appsecret_proof' => $appsecret_proof,
    'default_graph_version' => 'v2.8'
]);

// make an array of the data that has to be posted

$dataToPost = [
    'landingPage' => [
        'link' => 'https://www.fiverr.com/s2/e6d69807e0',
        'message' => 'Get a beautiful landing page or squeeze page for your business at $10 (exclusively on Fiverr).
The page will catch your audience\'s attention.
Get a working contact form with google reCaptcha on the page for free'
    ],
    'PhpMySQLApp' => [
        'link' => 'https://www.fiverr.com/s2/d8b0e8bcbb',
        'message' => 'Get a Php and MySQL application done for your business.
I will build any Php or Mysql application that you need.'
    ]
];

// make an array of groups that need to be posted in
$groups = array('Entrepreneur' => '168892346490054', 'Internet Marketing' => '163901963701922', 'Affiliate Marketing and money making' => '184087555102491',
    'Entrepreneurs Hut' => '366463540226995', 'Bangalore Start Up Connect' => '1546978348891191', 'Start Up Talky'=> '1628088717410164', 'Work from home' => '691810680861797',
    'Affiliate Marketing' => '127166864003113');

// make array for storing the gig names and groups
$gigs = [];
$groupNames = [];

// post each data into each group
foreach ($groups as $groupName => $groupId) {
    foreach ($dataToPost as $gigName => $gigLink) {
        try {
            // Returns a `Facebook\FacebookResponse` object
            $response = $fb->post('/' . $groupId . '/feed', $gigLink, token);

            // push gig names and group names into the vars
            array_push($gigs, $gigName);
            array_push($groupNames, $groupName);
        } catch (Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
            echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
            exit;
        } catch (Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
            echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
            exit;
        }

        $graphNode = $response->getGraphNode();

        echo $gigName . ' posted into group <b>' . $groupName . '</b> with id: ' . $graphNode['id'] . '<br/>';
    }
}

// set the mail subject
$mail->Subject = "Facebook Bot Posting";

// if successfully posted, then gigs and groupnames array
// will have items, then send an email informing it has been sent
if ( $gigs && $groupNames ) {
    $gigs = array_unique($gigs, SORT_REGULAR);
    $groupNames = array_unique($groupNames, SORT_REGULAR);

    $msg = "Gigs: <br/>";
    foreach ($gigs as $gig) {
        $msg .= "<b>$gig</b>, ";
    }

    $msg .= "Posted into groups <br/>";
    foreach ($groupNames as $groupName) {
        $msg .= "<b>$groupName</b>, ";
    }

    $mail->Body = $msg . "<br/> Sent from post2.";

    if ( $mail->send() ) {
        echo "Mail sent <br/>";
    } else {
        echo "Mail not sent. Something wrong <br/>";
    }

}
```